# How to keep the existing image if no new image selected?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I know there are similar questions. But I spend a whole day and couldn't fix my problem, Because I am completely noob. So, I'd appreciate it if someone provide an specific solution for my **ASP.Net Core** project.

If you need more info, Just ask.

Thanks.

---

So, My project is about Directors:

```
public class Director
{
    public Director()
    {
        Movies = new List<Movie>();
    }
    public int DirectorId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Bio { get; set; }
    public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public string PhotoURL { get; set; } // This field holds only the name of the photo, Not its URL.
}
```

---

My project save images in "wwwroot/uploads". Each director has an image. I can select a new image from my hard disk for each director.

**Problem:**

I can update a director image. But If I don't select a new image, the existing image will be deleted. I want to prevent it. I want it to keep the existing image if I don't select a new image.

---

**Edit.cshtl.cs**

```
public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly Context _context;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment;

    public EditModel(Context context, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        _context = context;
        this.hostingEnvironment = environment;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Director Director { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public IFormFile Image { set; get; }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? directorId)
    {
        if (directorId == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        Director = await _context.Director.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.DirectorId == directorId);

        if (Director == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Page();
    }

    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
    // more details, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int? directorId)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        if (this.Image != null)
        {
            var fileName = GetUniqueName(this.Image.FileName);
            var uploads = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
            var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, fileName);
            this.Image.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
            this.Director.PhotoURL = fileName; // Set the file name
        }

        _context.Attach(Director).State = EntityState.Modified;
        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!DirectorExists(Director.DirectorId))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }

    private bool DirectorExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Director.Any(e => e.DirectorId == id);
    }
    private string GetUniqueName(string fileName)
    {
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
        return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)
               + "_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 4)
               + Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    }



}
```

---

Edit.cshtml

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Director.DirectorId" />



        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Director.Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Director.Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Director.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Director.Country" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Director.Country" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Director.Country" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Director.Bio" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Director.Bio" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Director.Bio" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>



        <div>
            <img id="blah" src="~/uploads/@Model.Director.PhotoURL" />
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <div class="form-group" runat="server">
            <label asp-for="Director.PhotoURL" class="control-label"></label>
            <input type="file" asp-for="Image" class="form-control" id="imgInp" value="~/uploads/@Model.Director.PhotoURL" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Director.PhotoURL" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>

    </form>
```

---

site.js:

```
function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

    var reader = new FileReader();


    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); // convert to base64 string
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function () {
    if ($('#imgInp').get(0).files.length !== 0) {

        readURL(this);
    }
});
```

---

Edit page:

[image: If I press save without selecting a new image, It will delete the existing image.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to modify your code would be to do a get on the database and set the image path to the original image path if the new image path is null. This does have the disadvantage of an extra database call though:

```
if (this.Image != null)
{
    ...
}

else
{
    Director.PhotoURL = (await _context.Director.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.DirectorId == directorId))?PhotoURL;
}
```

Another option would be to store the original image path somewhere when you retrieve it from the database and then use it if the new image path is null. This would not involve an extra get. You could do something like:

```
[BindProperty]
public string OriginalImage { set; get; }

...

OriginalImage = Director.PhotoURL

...

<input type="hidden" asp-for="OriginalImage"/>

...

if (this.Image != null)
{
    ...
}

else
{
    Director.PhotoURL = OriginalImage;
}
```

Comment: The second solution works for me and It is not difficult at all.

Comment: As for the first solution, It was "?" or "."? Was "?" a typo?
Anyway, I edited your code and replaced the "?" with ".", But got this error: `InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Director' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'DirectorId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is to use an `else` clause in your OnPostAsync call here: `if (this.Image != null)`

Since you are setting the context to changed and doing an update, you are writing a null to the image. With an `else` you can do something like this:

`else {
     this.Director.PhotoURL = LastImage;
}`

As for how you get a value for LastImage, the easiest way is to pull it via a linq query using the `DirectorId` that was passed in (the same way you get the Director object a little above).